# Issues with .Find function returning errors when searching for a maximum value in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find and define a row which describes the maximum value in a range. The range is a column of numbers with decimal points which is imported into the sheet. I can find the max value but the .Find function is returning "object variable or with block variable not set" when I try and define the row it is in.

I know that this error is returned if the value is not found. MsgBox dMax just prior to the .Find operation shows that it has found the max value for the range.

The data set is a series of long positive and negative non integer numbers, e.g. -0.594396474479286. I've ensured that the data format is "general".

```
'finding highpoint

Dim dMax As Double
Dim HighPoint As Long

   With ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10000")
        dMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A2:A10000"))

        MsgBox dMax

        If dMax > 0 Then

         HighPoint = Range("A2:A10000").Find(What:=dMax, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False).Row


        End If
    End With
```

Can anyone point to what I have done wrong here? It seems like the .find function can't find the max value..

Comment: Change your `With` to : `With ActiveSheet` and use `HighPoint = Application.MATCH(Application.MAX(.Range("A:A")),.Range("A:A"),0)`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Should have used Match instead. What would you change if there was a chance that there would be two identical max values in the dataset?

Comment: Also, try `LookIn:=xlFormulas`

Answer (score 1):

Use the worksheet's Match function to locate the row containing the maximum number.

```
Dim dMax As Double
Dim HighPoint As Long

With ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

    dMax = application.Max(.cells)
    MsgBox dMax

    If dMax > 0 Then

        HighPoint = application.Match(application.Max(.cells), .cells, 0)

    End If
End With

debug.print HighPoint
```

Your own code may be suffering from a floating point decimal problem.

Watch your use of With, End With blocks. `.Range("A2:A10000")` within `ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10000")` is actually `.Range("A3:A10001")` on the worksheet and you were missing the prefix `.` in the second use of `Range("A2:A10000")`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looks like match is a better function for this application.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an "After" value outside your search range. You can simply delete this named parameter, or change it to

```
HighPoint = Range("A2:A10000").Find(What:=dMax, After:=Cells(2, 1), _
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Comment: Also this isn't entirely related, but it may help you in the future. If you are using MsgBox to display intermediate values to check for errors, replacing it with Debug.Print might save you some time (the values appear in the immediate window, show by pressing cntrl + G on Windows)

Comment: Thanks for the tip